# Continuous post on facebook wall problem in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am using facebook graph api to post a message on facebook wall in iphone App.It works fine.But when i continuously post on facebook wall(I post 20 messages per minute) further post is not permitted.

Why it is not allowing to post?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: R u posting same message or new ?

Comment: Different message from same app id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had the same problem.  As @ElanthiraiyanS says, it is done by the Facebook to avoid spam. However, you can able to post message from your app after a day.  It will be kept blocked for a day.

Answer (score 1):

Thats done by Facebook to avoid spam. Try posting using a different account.

Comment: It works fine from different account.But i need to post from that account.

Comment: That wont be possible using an API as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit on the number of graph api calls (per day I suppose) for each application.

You might also want to check if you have not set your application as Desktop Application (should be Web application) I did read on facebook platform developers forum that a desktop application has lower call limit then a web application.

here is the link : http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=23561

I hope this helps.